# Was there a "literate class" outside the Shi in Zhou-dynasty China?

Tags: social-history, ancient-china, philosophy

According to wikipedia, during [Zhou dynasty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zhou_dynasty#Culture_and_society) China's ...

> distinct class system, which lacked an organized clergy but saw the Shang Zi-clan yeomen become masters of ritual and ceremony known as **Shi** (士). When a dukedom was centralized, these people would find employment as government officials or officers. These hereditary classes were similar to Western knights in status and breeding, but like Western clergy were expected to be something of a scholar instead of a warrior. Being appointed, they could move from one state to another. Some would travel from state to state peddling schemes of administrative or military reform. Those who could not find employment would often end up teaching young men who aspired to official status. The most famous of these was Confucius ...

My question is if there where other broader societal classes where people might have a similar scholarly training, or might even work as advisors or teachers. Possible literate classes could be merchants, clergy, or even slaves or servants if those served as teachers or scribes.

Comment: On the one hand, this is a simple question. Yes, there was a _broader societal classes_ is the short answer. On the other hand, I just want to **clarify**, what do you mean _similiar scholarly training_? Are you asking if there were individuals who were trained as a scholar but were not called a scholar/gentry? That's a funny question in my mind. Hence, my need to clarify.

Comment: trained as a scholar but outside the "Shi" hereditary class

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace - what are you referring to, re _hypothesis_, i.e. evidence?

Comment: Ok ... I'm lost as you are now. Starting with _second literary class_ ... I hope I did not say that. The rest, i.e. the limited role of literary skills for general population in ancient China -- agreed. But you mentioned something that was hypothetical and needed evidence for. Is this what you're referring to, the _2nd literary class_?

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace If you refer to me, I don't have the hypothesis that there was but the question if. Evidence either way hopefullyprovied by an answer!

Answer (score 4):

The answer has to be no. In China, there were the four basic occupations at the time: the *shih* (literati), *nung* (peasantry), *kung* (artisans) and *shang* (merchants). Each occupation had its job and was supposed to focus on it, and the job of the *shi* was to fight, and later, to administrate, and to engage in scholarship. Thus, speaking of a literate class, the *shi* is the only one.

In Zhou dynasty China, membership of the *shih* class was mainly hereditary: to become a member of this literati class, one needs to be born into it. Although Confucius himself promoted education without barriers, i.e. *yu chiao wu lei* 有教無類, and actually did take students of humble descent (turning them into *shih*), the vast majority of *shih* acquired their status by birth.

Of course, when the *k'o-chiu* 科舉 examinations were introduced later, membership of the *shi* class became based on meritocracy, namely passing the exams.

Comment: Agreed. Straight-forward answer but I think non-Chinese readers probably need more verification (Wikipedia links).

Answer (score 3):

I do not have the citations on hand, but I believe Feng Youlan and Edward Shaughnessy have proposed that the Mohist movement may have taught writing to students outside the Shi class. IEP [says](http://www.iep.utm.edu/mozi/#H1):

> Some scholars speculate that Mozi and the Mohists probably came from a
>   lower social class than, for instance, the Confucians, but the
>   evidence is inconclusive and at best suggestive. Nevertheless, if the
>   conjecture is true, it could well explain the often repetitive and
>   artless style in which much of the Mozi is composed and the
>   anti-aristocratic stance of much Mohist doctrine, as well as why the
>   Mohists paid such attention to the basic economic livelihood of the
>   common people.

IEP is being polite. The book of *Mozi* is famous for its awful writing style (frequently amusing in English translation), and many people have suggested that it was written by multiple writers who lacked education in rhetoric and style, suggesting entire schools of pragmatic literacy outside the traditional literati.

Comment: The funny thing about this answer is that my question was prompted by some ruminations on the history of the Dao De Jing and the 'textual commune' that authored it.

Comment: @mart Shaughnessy thinks that the DDJ was written by ex-Shi hippies who turned on, tuned in and dropped out of the corrupt warlord courts.

Answer (score 2):

Officially, no -- there was not another Scholar (***shi* [士]**).

Culturally, the *literati* as a social class did not exist during a large part of the *[Zhou dynasty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zhou_dynasty)*, and only came into existence in late Zhou (*[Warring States](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Warring_States_period)*) period.

During this period of late Zhou (*I am narrowing this to Zhou because that was the question*), the populace was segregated into *[four occupations (roles)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four_occupations)*, in descending order of rank:

- Gentry/Scholars, ***shi* (士)** -- the elites, i.e. military commanders -- this class is the *literati* we've been looking at.
- Agricultural Producers -- ***nong* (农)** -- peasants, producers of foodstuff.
- Labourers -- ***gong* (工)** -- craftsmen. artisans, etc.
- Merchants -- ***shang* (商)** -- lowest because they do not produce (grow or create) their own.

This is the '*broader societal class*' part of the question.

**More Details**

But then it goes to mention *merchants* (as one example), and asked if there were trained as scholars. The short answer is they will not be trained per se by the Imperial court (*based on the classification*) but they can of course learn on his/her own. So, no *scholarly training* for merchants and slaves.

Finally, if you're asking if the title of Scholar (*shi*) is restricted to this hereditary class. Yes, it was, and the others (farmers, artisans & merchants) could **not** become Scholars via the *[Imperial (Civil Service) Examination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imperial_examination)*, which was only reserved for descendants of the *Shi*. Only much later, 6th century CE, could others try to qualify as a scholar and find work as a court servant (bureaucrat), i.e. during *[Sui Dynasty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sui_dynasty)*.

Having provided this answer,  and because we are of course narrating based on available textual material (and some material culture), it does not mean that ancient China is ***exactly as explained*** -- see below for context.

**More Context**

There's a problem with providing historical answers that are not sufficient, i.e. missing details. The natural temptation to be more thorough is, however, countered with a need for expediency; such is the need for convenience in our time-starved society today.

So, I'd like to ask readers of this answer to keep in mind the following context (as a frame of reference, which might help understand the narrative of the answer):

- Zhou dynasty (c.1050-256 BCE) - can be viewed as earlier *Western Zhou (c.1050-771 BCE)* and later *Eastern Zhou (770-221 BCE)*
- Eastern Zhou should be separated into sub-periods of  Spring and Autumn Period (770-c.480 BCE) and Warring States Period (c.480-221 BCE).
- Western Zhou is the *idealised* unified elite culture of many Chinese classical texts such as Confucius (c. 551-479 BCE) *Analects*, Mencius (371-289 BCE) *Mencius*, Xun Zi (Hsun Tzu) (298-238) *Xunzi* -- none of the classical Confucian historians/theorists lived in Western Zhou era.
- The Later (Eastern) Zhou was a period of decline and much confusion, i.e. warring states, *[100 Schools of Thought](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hundred_Schools_of_Thought)* --- all competing for legitimacy with the Imperial court(*s*).
- Into this mix, we now have from Qin (at the latest) and late Zhou (at the earliest), a form of *[social control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_social_structure#Early_Imperial_Period)* via the Four Occupations classification. In terms of how well it reflected the society of ancient China, the best we can say is that it is based on an *idealised structure*.

Comment: Lol, I did not see xuq01's answer. Don't ask me why. I've essentially said what he said but in a much longer approach.